# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ob":"^7.0.0","istanbu'

Tags: node.js, npm

Since today nativesctipt is not working, almost anything that I do with npm gives this error

```
$ npm install -g nativescript

> nativescript@6.3.3 preuninstall /home/me/.local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node preuninstall.js

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ob":"^7.0.0","istanbu'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2020-01-25T18_13_57_681Z-debug.log
Error while loading nativescript-starter-kits is: Command npm failed with exit code 1
/home/me/.local/bin/tns -> /home/me/.local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
/home/me/.local/bin/nativescript -> /home/me/.local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns

> nativescript@6.3.3 postinstall /home/me/.local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node postinstall.js

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ob":"^7.0.0","istanbu'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2020-01-25T18_14_05_772Z-debug.log
Error while loading nativescript-starter-kits is: Command npm failed with exit code 1
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/me/.local/share/.nativescript-cli/extensions/node_modules/nativescript-starter-kits/package.json'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ nativescript@6.3.3
updated 1 package in 24.848s
```

Comment: hey, did you try below solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below steps:

1. Clear npm cache

   `npm cache clean`
2. Install the package.

   `npm install -g nativescript`

**Note: if still not working do `npm cache clean --force` and then install**